# Extracting text ending with escape characters in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to parse the key details of PDF papers via python, and extract the title of the paper, authors and their email

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

reader = PdfReader("paper.pdf")
text = ""
for page in reader.pages:
    text += page.extract_text() + "\n"
```

returns the raw text of the PDF

```
'Title\nGoes\nHere\nAuthor Name (sdsd@mail.net)\nUniversity of Teeyab\nSeptember 6, 2022\nSome text in the Document.\n'
```

I have a function which removes the newlines and tabs etc

```
def remove_newlines_tabs(text):
    """
    This function will remove all the occurrences of newlines, tabs, and combinations like: \\n, \\.
    
    arguments:
        input_text: "text" of type "String". 
                    
    return:
        value: "text" after removal of newlines, tabs, \\n, \\ characters.
        
    Example:
    Input : This is her \\ first day at this place.\n Please,\t Be nice to her.\\n
    Output : This is her first day at this place. Please, Be nice to her. 
    
    """
    
    # Replacing all the occurrences of \n,\\n,\t,\\ with a space.
    Formatted_text = text.replace('\\n', ' ').replace('\n', ' ').replace('\t',' ').replace('\\', ' ').replace('. com', '.com')
    return Formatted_text
```

which returns

```
'Title Goes Here Author Name (sdsd@mail.net) University of Teeyab September 6, 2022 Some text in the Document. '
```

which makes it easy to extract the email. How can I extract the Title of the PDF and the authors? The title is the most important thing but I am not sure of the best approach...

Comment: if the title can be identified with the text before the 1st `\n` you should split the list before apply the _remove_newlines_tabs function_

Comment: `title, author, *other = text.split('\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution using regex based on the following assumptions

- every word of title is separated by a newline character `\n`
- every word of author is separated by a whitespace
- email address is always wrapped by parentheses `()`

```py
import re


test_string = 'Title\nGoes\nHere\nAuthor Name (sdsd@mail.net)\nUniversity of Teeyab\nSeptember 6, 2022\nSome text in the Document.\n'

# \w matches characters, numbers, and underscore
# \s matches whitespace and \t\n\r\f\v
# first, let's extract string that appears before parentheses
result = re.search(r"([\w\s]+)", test_string)
print(result) # <re.Match object; span=(0, 28), match='Title\nGoes\nHere\nAuthor Name '>

# clean up leading and trailing whitespaces using strip() and
# split the string by \n to separate title and author
title_author = result[0].strip().split("\n")
print(title_author) # ['Title', 'Goes', 'Here', 'Author Name']

# join the words of title as a single string
title = " ".join(title_author[:-1])
author = title_author[-1]

print(title) # Title Goes Here
print(author) # Author Name
```